# Php won't display value

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the id of a product knowing its name. It works on mySql, and `$result->num_rows` is 1, still `$idprod` is NULL. What am I doing wrong?

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM products where name='$prod'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
$idprod=$row['id'];
if($result->num_rows == 0)
echo "nah";
else echo $idprod;
```

Comment: have you checked what `$row` actually contains? Either using xdebug or var_dump..

Comment: I'm seeing now that it's NULL, but it works on mySql..

Comment: echo your `$sql` and try that query on SQL CLI

Comment: I did and it works

Comment: have you var_dump'd `$prod`? and `$conn` to make sure it's all there

Comment: also you can optimise your script: `if (!$conn->query($sql)) {}` and `echo ($result->num_rows == 0 ? 'nah' : $idprod);`

Comment: `$prod` and `$conn` are ok. Optimising the script displays nothing, doesnt show neither 'nah' or the id

Comment: I think you need `while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your `$result` variable, i think all you need is adding an index to your echo like `$idprod = $row[0]['id']`.
Here is how i would do it and that works (with PDO):

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM products where name='$prod'");
$result->execute();
if ($result->errorInfo()[0] != "00000") {
    echo "Error: " . $result->errorInfo()[2];
 } else {
    $row = $result->fetchAll();
    $idprod=$row[0]['id'];
    if(count($result) == 0)
    echo "nah";
    else echo $idprod;
}
```

Comment: Still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

```html
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id FROM products where name='$prod'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$result)
  {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
  }
// if there is one record only
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$id = ($row['id']);
echo $id;

//if there is a multiple records
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
 {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. "<br>";
 }
```